# Why does adding a user and setting an SUID for it throws me the "Operation not permitted" error?

Tags: centos, chmod, setuid, suid

I am setting SUID for a new user tommy to run the same commands as root but it goes down like this:

```
[root@192 ~]# useradd tommy
[root@192 ~]# su - tommy
[tommy@192 ~]$ chmod u+s /usr/bin/ls
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/bin/ls': Operation not permitted`
```

Do I need to add this user to sudoers file in order to execute this command successfully or what?

Comment: you're trying to set SUID for the command `/usr/bin/ls` as user tommy, which doesn't have the rights to do that - since `/usr/bin/ls` is likely to be owned by root - I think what you're trying to achieve and what you're actually doing are two completely different things anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX I was just trying to learn setUID and setGID. I know both are different things.

Answer (score 1):

If you want user `tommy` to be able to run `/usr/bin/ls` as root, then you need to configure `sudo` to allow that.  e.g. in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
tommy ALL = /usr/bin/ls
```

**You do not need to change the permissions of `ls` to make it setuid**.  The elevation to root is performed by `sudo` if the rules in `/etc/sudoers` (and files in `/etc/sudoers.d/`) allow it.

In fact, **you should NOT make `ls` setuid** - that would make `ls` run as root (the owner, unless you've changed it) every time it is executed, no matter who executes it.

Comment: Still no change: https://imgur.com/a/4E6EI7V

Comment: I repeat:  **You do not need to change the permissions of ls to make it setuid**, and, more importantly, **you should NOT make ls setuid**.